# How to use d3.layout.cloud.js to create a word cloud with a csv containing both words and their weight?

Tags: javascript, csv, dictionary, d3.js, word-cloud

I am using the d3.layout.cloud.js to make a word cloud and the source data is a .csv table containing both words and their weight.Now I can show all the words in the cloud but cannot put every word's weight on its own.
Someone help me out here and thank you all very much ;p

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var fill = d3.scale.category20();
    d3.csv("wordTfIdf.csv",function(data){
    console.log(data);
    var word = [];
    var value = [];
    for(i in data)
    {
        word[i] = data[i].word;
        value[i] = data[i].tfidf;
    }
    console.log(word);
    console.log(value);
    d3.layout.cloud().size([960, 600])
      **.words(word.map(function(d) {return {text: d, size: 10 + Math.random() * 50};}))**
      .rotate(function() { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90; })
      .font("Impact")
      .fontSize(function(d) { return d.size; })
      .on("end", draw)
      .start();
   function draw(words) {
      d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 960)
        .attr("height", 600)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(150,150)")
        .selectAll("text")
        .data(words)
        .enter().append("text")
        .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
        .style("font-family", "Impact")
        .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i); })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
        })
        .text(function(d) { return d.text; });
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't include an example of your `"wordTfIdf.csv"` which would really help to answer this question but I'm from the looks of it it's something like this:

```
word,tfidf
one, 20
two, 30
three, 40
four, 50
five, 60
six, 70
seven, 80
nine, 90
```

Where word is the text to display and tfidf is the font-size of the the word.

The first step is to get this into a format that the `d3.layout.cloud()` likes, mainly an array of objects with `text` and `size` properties.  We can use [d3.csv's](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#parse) parsing to help us.

```
// give d3.csv two functions
// the first to parse each row
// the second to draw the cloud
d3.csv("wordTfIdf.csv", function(d) {
    return { // for each csv row return an object with text and size
      text: d.word,
      size: +d.tfidf // cast this to a number with +
    }
  },
  function(data) {
    d3.layout.cloud().size([960, 600]).words(
      data // data is already in the correct format
    )
```

Here's an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/e90KNkFtjn7reDzPYtsC?p=preview).